# For this Binary Search Tree method. I don't understand how it puts it in order from smallest to largest numbers

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

So I understand that it calls the method recursively. However I'm not sure how it would output the larger nodes (the right side of the nodes).
Thank you!

```
void InOrderSmallestToLargest(BST* root)
  {
    if(root==NULL)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Ordered from smallest to largest
    InOrderSmallestToLargest (root->left);
    cout << root->data<<'\n';
    InOrderSmallestToLargest (root->right);
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `InOrderSmallestToLargest (root->right);` take care of that?  It may help clarify your question if you can explain how you are able see the "left side" nodes printing.

Comment: Best way to find out, create a BST with a few nodes and the run through the code with your debugger.  That will let you step through the code so you can see exactly how the calls get ordered.

Comment: Be aware that for *any* sub-tree one and the same rule applies: All values in left child-tree are smaller (or equal) to the current root's value, all values in right child tree are greater (or equal). So wherever you are currently located in the sub-tree the smallest value to be printed first is somewhere in the left child tree – unless there isn't one any more, in which case the current value is the smallest one. That's why you first recurse into left child tree, and there the same again...

Comment: Once all values smaller – if they exist – are printed, you print current root's one, finally the same for the values greater, i.e. the right child tree.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted describes a tree-traversal scheme called pre-order (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order,_NLR )

The cout will print the current nodes value after traversing all the left Nodes (until a leafe is reched) and the continue the traversal on the right Nodes, and then print their values

Comment: Thank you, how you described it made sense.

Comment: pre-order is **not** the order you need to get the output in sorted order. I don't understand why this is marked as accepted.

Comment: I described the implemented traversal scheme and how the right nodes are printed. I did not a statement on the order of the nodes.  But you are right, you have to use In-order, LNR traversal to get the correct order on a binary search tree. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

In a Binary Search Tree (BST) this rule is true for *all* nodes:

- All values in the node's left subtree (if any) are *less than or equal to* the node's own value
- All values in the node's right subtree (if any) are *greater than or equal to* the node's own value

The recursive function uses this property. The reasoning is that in order to output the values in order, *all* the values in the root's left subtree should be listed before its own value, and *all* the values from the root's right subtree should be listed *after* its own value.

If we apply the same reasoning in the left subtree and in the right subtree, then it is clear we will never output values in the wrong order.